# What to do if Optional Parameter concept doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a JS function which takes a value from a textbox based on the Radio button selected.

Example: If RadioButton **No** is Selected, values is teken from **TextBox A**, else if RadioButton **Yes** is selected, Value is taken from **TextBox B**. The following script is in my view

```
$('#btnVolunteerSaveBtn').on('click', function() { // on click of save button
  if (document.getElementById('RadioNo').checked) { //ID of radio button NO
    var checking = $('#Donation').val(); //ID of textbox from where the value is to be taken if RadioButton No is selected
    if (checking == "") {
      //if nothing is entered, stop from saving in DB
    } else {
      x = $('#Donation').val(); //ID of textbox from where the value is to be taken if RadioButton No is selected
      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("DonationValue","VolunteerInfo")',
        data: {
          name: x
        },
        type: "POST"
      });
    }
  } else {
    x = $('#GetNames').val(); //ID of textbox from where the value is to be taken if RadioButton Yes is selected
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("DonationValue","VolunteerInfo")',
      data: {
        name: x
      },
      type: "POST"
    });
  }
});
```

Till here it seems to work fine. Now coming to the controller, I have a function `DonationValue`

**My Question:**

1. How can I pass the `name` parameter above?
2. If nothing is filled in TextBox with id #Donation, how do I stop
   from saving the form in the DB?

**My Attempt:**

I tried doing

```
public string DonationValue(string name = null)
{
    return name; //Trying to pass this value above
}
```

This didn't help. It resolved the error but the passed value was always null. I also tried a couple of other things but none helped.

**Edited:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddVolunteer(VolunteerInfo viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("AddVolunteer", viewModel);
    }

    var volunteer = new VolunteerInfo()
    {
        Name = viewModel.Name,
        BirthdayDateTime = viewModel.BirthdayDateTime,
        Address = viewModel.Address,
        PhoneNumber = viewModel.PhoneNumber,
        EmailAddress = viewModel.EmailAddress,
        OccasionsID = viewModel.OccasionsID,
        DonationForWhom = _DonationValue
    };

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(volunteer.DonationForWhom))
    {
        _context.VolunteerInfos.Add(volunteer);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return //something to save state so that user doesnt have to enter all the values again
}

[HttpPost]
public void DonationValue(string name)
{
    _DonationValue = name;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to put the `[HttpPost]` attribute on your `DonationValue` method

Comment: @RuiJarimba: Nope. I tried that. Doesn't work.

Comment: @Priyanka Dembla, where is your `ha` parameter in above code?

Comment: @ershoaib: I meant name parameter. Please see now. Thank you for correcting me,

Comment: @Priyanka Dembla, did u checked `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(volunteer.DonationForWhom)) {_context.VolunteerInfos.Add(volunteer);
        _context.SaveChanges();  }`

Comment: Ok that would probably solve my second problem. How about the first?

Comment: The accepted answer of a static field is almost certainly *not* what you want, unless you really want your web application to only be usable by one person at a time - if there are multiple users going through the flow, you could cause a lot of confusion. Fundamentally you need to store the state somewhere: either pass it back to the client to present in the next request, or store it server-side associated with the user's session in some form. Keeping it as static, global state is *not* a good idea.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I think it will just serve as a Register form. However, if multiple people are trying to register at the same time, will it cause trouble?

Comment: @PriyankaDembla: Yes, absolutely, because you've got *one* static variable, across the whole server, regardless of who's using it. Imagine if an e-commerce site had a single shopping basket: I add something into the basket, and then another user pays for it! That's not what you want.

Comment: @ershoaib: I think that you may have misunderstood what `static` means.

Comment: @PriyankaDembla: please try to avoid "doesn't work" as a response to someone here - it is one of the most unhelpful failure reports within the whole field of software engineering. Try to be as expansive as you can, and be aware that if you are seeking a new idea, you need to provide new (and detailed) information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Daisy Shipton. 
Is this a better solution?

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $('#btnVolunteerSaveBtn').on('click', function() { // on click of save button
                debugger;
                if (document.getElementById('RadioNo').checked) { //ID of radio button NO
                    var checking = $('#Donation').val(); //ID of textbox from where the value is to be taken if RadioButton No is selected
                    if (checking == "") {
                        //if nothing is entered, stop from saving in DB
                    }
                    else {
                        var x = $('#Donation').val(); //ID of textbox from where the value is to be taken if RadioButton No is selected
                        var jsonObject = {
                            "textValue": x,
                            "isRadioSelected": "true" // show the radio is selected
                        };

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("AddVolunteer", "VolunteerInfo")',
                            data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            error: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            },
                            success: function (response) {
                                alert(response);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                else {
                    var jsonObject2 = {
                        "textValue": $('#GetNames').val(),
                        "isRadioSelected": "false" // show the radio is not selected
                    };

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("AddVolunteer", "VolunteerInfo")',
                        data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject2),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        })
    </script>
```

In my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddVolunteer(VolunteerInfo volunteerInfo)
    {
        if (volunteerInfo.isRadioSelected)
        {
            //something
        }
        else
        {
           //something
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: slightly change in your solution, view my newly posted solution may it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Client calls to `DonationValue` post method with name paramter

e.g. `name="abc"`

```
[HttpPost]
public string DonationValue(string name = null)  // name = "abc"
    {
        return name; //Trying to pass this value above
    }
```

This returned value to be stored in client side say variable `retunedDonationValue`

If you don't pass any name parameter then above post method does return empty string then just set `retunedDonationValue = ''`

2) Now you have to pass above `retunedDonationValue` to your post method in posted json object like

```
var jsonObject = 
                {
                    "Name" = "YourName",
                    "BirthdayDateTime" = "YourBirthdayDateTime",
                    "Address" = "YourAddress",
                    "PhoneNumber" = "YourPhoneNumber",
                    "EmailAddress" = "YourEmailAddress",
                    "OccasionsID" = "YourOccasionsID",
                    "DonationForWhom" = retunedDonationValue  //Note here
                }
```

3) And pass this post data to http call to AddVolunteer

```
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("AddVolunteer", "VolunteerInfo")',
                        data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    });
```

4) And your action method is look like

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddVolunteer(VolunteerInfo viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("AddVolunteer", viewModel);
        }

        var volunteer = new VolunteerInfo()
        {
            Name = viewModel.Name,
            BirthdayDateTime = viewModel.BirthdayDateTime,
            Address = viewModel.Address,
            PhoneNumber = viewModel.PhoneNumber,
            EmailAddress = viewModel.EmailAddress,
            OccasionsID = viewModel.OccasionsID,
            DonationForWhom = viewModel.DonationForWhom
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(volunteer.DonationForWhom))
        {
            _context.VolunteerInfos.Add(volunteer);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View(viewModel);

    }
```

Comment: @Priyanka Dembla, let me know if it help you or not :)